# Callback value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever i try to fetch the return value from a function it returns undefined.

Tried callbacks, 
Tried async

```
let express = require('express');
let fs = require('fs');
let router = express();
let mysql = require('mysql');
const session = require('express-session');

router.use(session({
    secret: 'something random.exe',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7600000),
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 7600000),
    }
}));

async function logins (username, password) {
    mysql.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?", [username], (err, rows) => {
        return "test";
    })
}

module.exports = {
    login: async (request, response, username, password) => {
        logins("username", "password", (getResponse) => {
            return console.log(getResponse);
        })
    }
};
```

The console always returns undefined.

Comment: Instead of `return console.log(getResponse);`, use `return getResponse`.

Comment: @randomSoul — That won't make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `logins` you pass it three arguments:

1. "username"
2. "password"
3. a function

Look at the definition of `logins`:

> ```
> async function logins (username, password) {
> ```

It only does anything with the first **two** arguments.

Your callback function never gets used.

Rewrite `logins` to call it.

---

Also note that you've labeled it as `async`, but you aren't `await`ing any promises … so that is probably a mistake.

Comment: Pardon me, what do you mean by rewrite logins?

Comment: @BasKruithof — Edit the source code of the function named logins. Change it. You have written it wrong, so rewrite it.

Comment: @BasKruithof add callback function to parameter to `logins` function.  `async function logins (username, password, callback) {` and call it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are not aware of `async/await` keyword. This type of issue occurs when you try to call any function without the keyword `await`.

**WRONG FORMAT**

```
 const userUtils = {};

 userUtils.login = async () => {
 try {
     // Your business logic 
 } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
     throw err;
 }
};

userUtils.test = async () => {
    try {
        const result = userUtils.login();
        console.log(result); // It will undefined
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
};

userUtils.test();
```

In the above code, you will get `undefined` as **result** variable.

**CORRECTION**

```
const result = await userUtils.login();
```

Don't forget to write a keyword `await` while calling any promises.

**Note: You can only use `async/await` when you need to handle any promises. It can't work directly on callbacks**

**WRONG FORMAT [await while callbacks]**

```
userUtils.test = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await userUtils.login(args, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
            return data;
        });
        console.log(result); // It will undefined
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
};
```

I hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But i still can't get any value from my mysql callback. I've tried everything at this point and nothing works.